# How to to disable customer required place order to chat with vendor

Tags: php, chat, e-commerce, scrypt

Hello i bought ecommerce php script i have some basic coding skills i want to customize but in this script customer cannot chat with seller until he placed order so how can i disable it.[this picture show after placed order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKyWH.jpg) [this picture show Before placed order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxEyJ.jpg)

I tried to check php on chat but i dont see any commands because i expected to saw something like "order required"

Comment: Post the code so that we could help you. Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Push the code to GitHub create an issue for someone to help you fix it. Because from you description you need an upgrade to the script not fixing a bug.